# angular 6, build can't load images on Firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, command-line-interface, firebase-hosting

I'm unable to load images from the assets folder after deploy the angular app to firebase hosting. (build --prod)
when run on localhost the images show.
All other things are loading properly.
this is my package json
cli: ~6.2.0-beta.2
firebase-tools: 4.1.0

```
{
  "name": "protocols",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "ng build --prod && firebase deploy"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.8.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.1.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mat-progress-buttons": "^6.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

tried at appComponent

```
<img src="../assets/image.jpg">
<img src="/assets/image.jpg">
<img src="assets/image.jpg">
```

none of this work.

hosting settings at firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
"public": "dist",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]}
```

Are there some trick on the firebase? rewrites? someone can help me!

Comment: Are you from the UAE or India? There's an ongoing issue with the Realtime Database right now. [Link to incident](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Realtime%20Database/18051)

Comment: I'm from Brazil, using us-central server. I don't think it is related to RD ongoing issue. I reproduced the same project (just hosting) with angular cli 6.0.3 and firebase-tools 4.0.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images loading now from assets in angular 6.1.3 after firebase deploy! Found the solution finally, well it works for me. The issue is the tsconfig.json change:

```
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
```

to:

```
"outDir": "./dist",
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with static assets after deploying to Firebase hosting, even though they worked fine when serving from localhost.  I had to change from
`<img src="/src/assets/img/pricing_comparison.PNG">` to
`<img src="/assets/img/pricing_comparison.PNG">`.

(p.s. I tried changing my tsconfig.json file according to the accepted answer, but this didn't change or resolve my error)

Comment: Dont know how it works, but it helped me. Thanks, sir Kat

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Here is the solution i tried

1. Open **tsconfig.json** change:

   `"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc"`,

   to:

   `"outDir": "./dist"`
2. Open **angular.json**. make sure assets configurations are as like below

```json
       "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
```

3. Change in img tag `<br>`
   `src="/src/assets/img/pricing_comparison.PNG"` to `<br>`
   `src="/assets/img/pricing_comparison.PNG"`.

Comment: I tried this solution, and many others, none worked. The only solution that worked was moving the asset file to the public file in the server, it is not nice, and elegant, but was the only solution that worked! I have to say that it started after I started using laizy load, before that, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in localhost

juste use url like

```
#login {
    background-image: url('/assets/app-assets/img/gallery/login-bg.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

in your CSS or html component, this works for me.
just change the image url from `/src/assets/your_image.png` to `/assets/your_image.png`

here is my angular version

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 12.8.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.2
@angular/cli                      8.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.2
@schematics/angular               8.2.2
@schematics/update                0.802.2
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0
```