# Missing image link after deploy on firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

The app working nicely at localhost and the image also showing properly without any problem. But after build using ng build --prod and deploy on firebase hosting the image is showing missing link. I have also try to solve this using "/assets/loading.svg". But also the image source is missing.

Here is my code

```
<div class="in-progress">
                <img src="assets/loading.svg">
        </div>
```

Here is firebase.json

```
{  "hosting": {
"public": "dist/bloodpoint",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]  }}
```

Comment: Are you getting a "404 not found" error? Or some other error (perhaps CORS)?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853387/angular-6-build-cant-load-images-on-firebase-hosting

Comment: Are you from the UAE or India? There's an ongoing issue with the Realtime Database right now. [Link to incident](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Realtime%20Database/18051)

Comment: Here is not found link https://blood-point-f9eb3.firebaseapp.com/assets/loading.svg